# How would I find the longest string per row in a data frame and print the row number if it exceeds a certain amount

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a program which searches through a data frame and if any of the items in it are above 50 characters long, print the row number and ask if you want to continue through the data frame.

```
threshold = 50 

mask = (df.drop(columns=exclude, errors='ignore')
          .apply(lambda s: s.str.len().ge(threshold))
        )

out = df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)]
```

I tried using this, but I don't want to drop the rows, just print the row numbers where the strings exceed 50

Input:

```
0 "Robert","20221019161921","London"
1 "Edward","20221019161921","London"
2 "Johnny","20221019161921","London"
3 "Insane string which is way too longggggggggggg","20221019161921","London"
```

Output:

```
Row 3 is above the 50-character limit.
```

I would also like the program to print the specific value or string which is too long.

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: an short example of your input and the matching expected output would be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
exclude = []
threshold = 30

mask = (df.drop(columns=exclude, errors='ignore')
          .apply(lambda s: s.str.len().ge(threshold))
        )

s = mask.any(axis=1)

for idx in s[s].index:
    print(f'row {idx} is above the {threshold}-character limit.')
    s2 = mask.loc[idx]
    for string in df.loc[idx, s2.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)]:
        print(string)
```

Output:

```
row 3 is above the 30-character limit.
"Insane string which is way too longggggggggggg","20221019161921","London"
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Would it be possible to print the specific value or string which is too long?

Comment: @CURNCHTOASTCRU yes, can you update the question?

Comment: I updated it for you

Comment: How does my code work for you?

Comment: The code works well, is there a way to show the specific field which is too long though?

Comment: See if the update is what you want